# Carousel no ReactJs

Tags: react, front-end, carousel

Olá,estou iniciando minha jornada como frontend e gostaria de saber como fazer com que os pontos num carousel possam ser clicados além de deixar as imagens mudando de forma automática? OBS1.:(Usei a biblioteca Emotion e se precisar posso colocar parte do código criado para os pontos aqui). OBS2.: Devo fazer algo parecido com os eventos de onClick que são utilizados para os buttons?

Comment: é bom você colocar o exemplo minimo!